# background image looks bad when stretching

Tags: css, background-image

I got some sort of forum page and a a possibility to comment on it, so the page becomes bigger according to the amount of comments placed on the page. Now my background is stretching obviously, but the problem is my image looks very bad. So I know it wont look bad when I use an image with a pattern, but is there a different way to use a normal background and not making it look bad? This is my CSS btw:

```
background-size:cover;
background-image:url('lol.jpg');
background-repeat:no-repeat;
```

Comment: may supersized can help you: http://buildinternet.com/project/supersized/

Comment: try using `background-attachment: fixed;`

Comment: @caramba I can't access the website you have provided.

Comment: @Mr.Alien Thanks totally forgot about it! Of course :D

Comment: @Mr.Alien provide it as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inorder to prevent that, you should use [`background-attachment: fixed;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-attachment), using this, will prevent the image to get scrolled along the page. This will keep the image static at the back.

```
selector {
   background-image: url(YOUR_URL_HERE);
   background-size: cover;
   background-attachment: fixed;
}
```

[Info](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background), if you are interested to use short hand syntax instead of writing each property.

Answer (score 1):

Use the CSS3 property `background-size`:

```
#selector {
    background-size: 100% auto; /* width and height, can be %, px or whatever */
}
```

This is available for modern browsers, since 2012.

Answer (score 0):

***Choise one of them***

**CSS3**

```
background: url(images/bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;
```

**T1**

```
img.bg {
  /* Set rules to fill background */
  min-height: 100%;
  min-width: 1024px;

  /* Set up proportionate scaling */
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;

  /* Set up positioning */
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1024px) { /* Specific to this particular image */
  img.bg {
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -512px;   /* 50% */
  }
}
```

**T2**

```
<div id="bg">
  <img src="images/bg.jpg" alt="">
</div>

#bg {
  position: fixed; 
  top: -50%; 
  left: -50%; 
  width: 200%; 
  height: 200%;
}
#bg img {
  position: absolute; 
  top: 0; 
  left: 0; 
  right: 0; 
  bottom: 0; 
  margin: auto; 
  min-width: 50%;
  min-height: 50%;
}
```

**jQuery**

```
<img src="images/bg.jpg" id="bg" alt="">

#bg { position: fixed; top: 0; left: 0; }
.bgwidth { width: 100%; }
.bgheight { height: 100%; }

$(window).load(function() {    

    var theWindow        = $(window),
        $bg              = $("#bg"),
        aspectRatio      = $bg.width() / $bg.height();

    function resizeBg() {

        if ( (theWindow.width() / theWindow.height()) < aspectRatio ) {
            $bg
                .removeClass()
                .addClass('bgheight');
        } else {
            $bg
                .removeClass()
                .addClass('bgwidth');
        }

    }

    theWindow.resize(resizeBg).trigger("resize");

});
```

http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/